# Read current gunicorn worker connections

Tags: gunicorn

Gunicorn has a setting called [worker connections](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-connections), which is:

> The maximum number of simultaneous clients.

Is there any way to read or track this value on a gunicorn server? I'm wondering if my server ever gets close to the 1000 connection limit. If so, I may consider increasing the worker or worker connection count.

I don't see any way to do this in the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html).